# Venturi effect and velocity of the liquid (or air)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I know that based on the Venturi effect, the velocity of a liquid (or air) going from a large sectional tube to a narrow sectional tube will increase. So, what happens if the liquid (or air) goes from a narrow sectional tube to a large sectional tube ?

Comment: The reverse: the speed will decrease.

Comment: @md2perpe: … but only in subsonic conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the flow speed in the narrow section:

- If it is subsonic, the flow will slow down while its pressure increases. Depending on the pressure gradient, the flow might separate from the tube wall and show a chaotic flow behavior outside of the core flow.
- If the speed of sound is reached in the narrow section, a widening tube downstream will cause the flow to accelerate further while pressure continues to drop. Now the details depend on the pressure downstream: If it is high enough, the flow will suddenly decelerate in a straight shock.